# Why does v-hover over v-btn give a warning in Chrome?

Tags: vuetify.js

To make the hover effect of a v-btn node in vuetify more visible I use the following code:

```
<v-hover v-slot:default="{ hover }" open-delay="200" class="ma-1">
   <v-btn color="primary"
    v-if="..." v-on:click="..." :elevation="hover ? 16 : 2"
   >
    Button Title
   </v-btn>
 </v-hover>
```

It is working, but in Chrome I get the warning "v-hover should only contain a single element".
Any advice to avoid this?

Answer (score 4):

The `v-if` removes the `<v-btn/>` element on the DOM so when `showBtn` is set to false, `<v-hover/>` is saying that it has no child.

Use [`v-show`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show), instead of `v-if`, so the `<v-btn/>` element will not be removed entirely from the DOM. It will just hide it (similar to `display: none;`). OR put the `v-if` in the `<v-hover/>` element instead.

See this demo at [codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-grass-s080h?file=/src/components/Playground.vue:817-833)